# Ruby class initialize (constructor) is private method or public method?

Tags: ruby, access-specifier

Is initialize method (constructor) private or public in ruby?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's see:

```
class Test
  def initialize; end
end

p Test.new.private_methods.sort.include?(:initialize)
```

This prints `true`, so `initialize` is a private method. This makes sense, it is only called by the `new` class method if the object is created. If we want, we can do something like this:

```
class Test
  def initialize
    @counter = 0
  end

  def reset!
    initialize
  end
end
```

Misusing the constructor like this could however lead to problems if it does more than simple variable initialization.

Comment: You can also call `initialize` of an object by `obj.send(:initialize)`.

Answer (score 4):

The `initialize` method in a class automatically becomes Private.

You can check it using:

```
puts ClassName.private_methods.sort
```